# Dataflow Template Metadata regex definition with escaped chars

Tags: json, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am creating a Dataflow Flex template and I would like to define the input parameters as documented here
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#metadata

I have configured my template with the following JSON

```
{
  "name": "My name",
  "description": "my long description",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "outputTopic",
      "label": "Pub/Sub ingest topic",
      "helpText": "Pub/Sub topic to publish result"
    },
    {
      "name": "bigQueryProject",
      "label": "BigQuery project",
      "helpText": "BigQuery google project"
    },
    {
      "name": "tempLocation",
      "label": "GCS Temp Location",
      "helpText": "GCS Location for storing temporary files",
      "regexes": [
        "gs://.*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "startDate",
      "label": "Start Date",
      "isOptional": true,
      "helpText": "Start date in the format YYYY-MM-DD or use 'YESTERDAY' as default",
      "regexes": [
        "^TODAY$|^YESTERDAY$|^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"
      ]
    }
    }
```

It works properly as I can see all parameters properly defined if I use the Google Console

[image: screenshot console]

However, when I execute the Job with all validated parameters, the request fails for an invalid REGEX defined

```
"(fb57dedae5c9fead): Template metadata contains invalid POSIX regex '^TODAY$|^YESTERDAY$|^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$': invalid escape sequence: \\d in \\d.
```

it Looks Like that the double escaping in the regex needed to create a valid JSON file, is not well interpreted by Dataflow.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try this` \\\\`, `(\\\\d)`? Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: wow that's it. The double escape from json to java and from java to actual string makes the job...please share it as answer even though I can't find it documented anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing is due to Invalid RegEx. As I mentioned in the comment you can solve this by using  `\\\\`, (\\\\d) .

Based on my understanding, you need to use `\\\\`, this will produce `\\` in the string and  `\` in the RegEx.You can understand this more by using the RegEx validator.

Comment: thanks again. it worked. It is really easy to encounter this issue but apparently, it is not very well documented..

Answer (score 0):

I think your `|` is not being interpreted as you expect.

Can you try using this format? This is what I see being used often:

`^(TODAY|YESTERDAY|\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})$`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make any difference. The formatted error is `Template metadata contains invalid POSIX regex '^(TODAY|YESTERDAY|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$': invalid escape sequence: \d in \d` if i try on console or Rest API, it shows the double \\ as problem of the regex

Comment: Did you try a single \ (\d)?

Comment: yes but it doesn't stage the template at all saying that the json is not valid...